# Getting error "400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand." while accessing the below method

Tags: python, angular, flask

```
    @endpoints.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
    def login():
        resp = {}
        try:
            users = user_collection
            # login_user = users.find_one({'username': request.form['name']})
            login_user = users.find({'username': request.form['username']})

            if login_user:
                if (request.form['password'] == login_user['password']):
                     session['username'] = request.form['username']
                # return True
                print("User logged in Successfully.")
            print("Invalid username/password combination")
            # return 'Invalid username/password combination'
            status = {
                "statusCode": "200",
                "statusMessage": "User logged in Successfully."
            }
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            status = {
                "statusCode": "400",
                "statusMessage": str(e)
            }
        resp["status"] = status
        return resp
```

I tried to submit POST request with JSON input from POSTMAN and expected the below response to be populated in POSTMAN response pane.

```
"statusCode": "200",
                "statusMessage": "User logged in Successfully."
```

Comment: Please provide the whole error traceback from console log.

Comment: I guess you’ll need to sent back valid JSON?